# Convert Datetime from mvc to Oracle in multiple Date/time format?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, datetime-format

This is the update's query in my project

```
string updateCurrentFlow = "update tc_lsn_file set tc_lsn10 = '2',tc_lsn12=to_date('" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("en-US")) + "','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') " +
" where tc_lsn01 =:DocNo and tc_lsn02 =:FlowNo and tc_lsn05 =:Plant and tc_lsn09 =:UserName";
```

I have tried many ways to update Datetime

```
to_date('" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

to_date('" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

to_date('" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

But when I change format datetime in computer, it's error.
My formats in computer include VietNam, Taiwan and English - US

This is the code when excute query

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
//Update CurrentFlow
cmd.CommandText = updateCurrentFlow;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DocNo", DocNo));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("FlowNo", FlowNo));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Plant", Plant));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("UserName", UserName));
//cmd.Parameters.Add("DateNow", OracleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
currentSigningFlowRowAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I don't know how to solve it? I have tried many many ways, please help.
Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

Simply use SQL string like this:

```
string updateCurrentFlow = "update tc_lsn_file set tc_lsn10 = '2',tc_lsn12 = :theDate 
    where tc_lsn01 =:DocNo and tc_lsn02 =:FlowNo and tc_lsn05 =:Plant and tc_lsn09 =:UserName";

cmd.Parameters.Add("theDate ", OracleDbType.Date, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = DateTime.Now;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DocNo", DocNo));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("FlowNo", FlowNo));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Plant", Plant));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("UserName", UserName));
```

The driver does proper conversion if needed, you don't have to take care about that.

Or maybe even simpler as this:

```
string updateCurrentFlow = "update tc_lsn_file set tc_lsn10 = '2',tc_lsn12 = SYSDATE
    where tc_lsn01 =:DocNo and tc_lsn02 =:FlowNo and tc_lsn05 =:Plant and tc_lsn09 =:UserName";

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DocNo", DocNo));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("FlowNo", FlowNo));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Plant", Plant));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("UserName", UserName));
```

Comment: When I change format into Vietnam in my computer, it's error also

Comment: ORA-01843: Not a Valid Month

Comment: Are you sure? Note, the date parameter must be added first. The order must match (unless you set `cmd.BindByName = true;`)

Comment: Oh, I have added it in last. But, I have tried this `to_date('" + DateTime.Now.ToString("M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("en-US")) + "','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`, it's ok. Anyway, thanks very much